# Install Standalone Package Without Internet Connection, No GUI, Windows 10

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, windows, standalone

I have MikTex 2.9 installed from the basic-miktex-2.9.6520-x64.exe file.  I need to install the Standalone package automatically without using the internet whatsoever as well as without any GUI interaction; it needs to be completely automatic.  I tried the following in the command prompt:

```
mpm --install standalone
```

But that requires a an internet connection.  I have standalone.tds.zip on my computer as well.  But

```
mpm --install "path_to_standalone.tds.zip"
```

doesn't work.  So I tried extracting the contents of this zip to the `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` directory.  Then I checked the MiKTeX Package Manager, and it reported that it still wasn't installed.  I don't get it and cannot figure this out to save my life.

**Given that I'm on Windows 10, have MikTex 2.9 installed, have the standalone.tds.zip file on my computer, what can I do to completely automatically install this package properly without any internet connection?**  Command line arguments are ideal here since I can put those in a batch script.

Comment: You can unzip the tds.zip  which whatever command line zip you have and then add the root with `initexmf --register-root path/to/the/root/of/the/tds`. If you want to use miktex tools to install, you need the lzma `http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/standalone.tar.lzma` and also the two `miktex-zz...` files from the same locations. Put all the files in some folder and use this folder as a local repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you, this actually worked.